# DevExpress not showing PostgreSQL foreign tables

Tags: postgresql, devexpress, devextreme

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL through DevExpress. The connection is returning the tables correctly except for the foreign tables.

Here's how I am connecting to PostgreSQL:

```
public DataConnectionParametersBase GetDataConnectionParameters(string name)
    {
            return new PostgreSqlConnectionParameters("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", XXXX, "dbName", "postgres_user", "XXXXXXXXX");
    }
```

This is working well and returning all tables. However, the foreign tables are not showing.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Any other PostgreSQL client that connects to this database, does see these foreign tables? And what about VIEW's, are they visible using DevExpress ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Yes, i can see those foreign tables when i connect to the PostgreSQL in Tableau for example. However not working in DevExpress.

Regarding the second point, yees i can see views and tables.

Comment: What happens when you create a view on top of one of these foreign tables? It could be that DevExpress doesn't support foreign tables because how how it's using pg_class to select the available data sources. Try this:  CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT * FROM your_foreign_table;

Comment: @FrankHeikens that actually worked thank you very much! If you want to post this as an answer so i can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trick your tool by using a VIEW on top of the foreign table:

```
CREATE VIEW x AS 
SELECT * FROM your_foreign_table;
```

Most likely DevExpress checks [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) just for the standard tables and views and isn't aware of new types of objects like foreign tables. But that's just an assumption.

Comment: Has there not been a better way to deal with this by now? on DevExpress side?